# Override apache2 virtualhost configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions

I'm trying to show a 403 error for everyone browsing my website except my own IP.

This is a temporary modification, so I don't want to change every of my virtualhost.

I've tried adding

```
<Directory /*>
        Deny from all
</Directory>
```

But everyone can still access my vhosts. What could I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such situations you can add to each virtualhost an include to a shared resource:

```
Include conf/shared-virtualhosts.conf
```

Then in this file add:

```
<Location />
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from ${yourallowedipaddress}
</Location>
```

When you are done just comment the file and reload your apache.

Answer (score 0):

Use a .htaccess file:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all   
allow from < your ip here >
```

httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html

Make sure the .htaccess feature is enabled